# Perl script handling with database

Tags: perl

Currently we are having perl script which will interact with database and will prompt user password for connecting to database.
Currently we are running that script manually and giving password to proceed.
But here we are planning to run that script at late night where it should not ask user password and interact with database and proceed with execution.
Is there any way we can do that like encryption/decryption something like that.
Please help

Comment: Please, insert the part of your script related to the place it's asking you the password, so people can help you based on it.

Comment: look into this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20461/how-can-i-avoid-putting-the-database-password-in-a-perl-script

Answer (score 0):

If the password becomes a parameter of the script (passed as environment variable for example to avoid being visible in ps), it becomes visible only to people logged with the same account. It may be possible to create a secured dedicated account to launch this script.

Comment: It is really helpful.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `Crypt::SaltedHash` see here. http://search.cpan.org/~gshank/Crypt-SaltedHash-0.09/lib/Crypt/SaltedHash.pm